# How to replace text starting with pattern?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this text opened in notepad++ 7.5.2 text editor :

```
- Note 1 message={"one":1}]
- Note 5 message={"two":2}]
- Note 2 message={"three":3}]
- Note 7 message={"four":4}]
```

For each line, I want to keep only the text between the brackets starting and ending brackets { } and the bracket themselves. I tried a regex `- Note.* message=` in https://regex101.com/ and it works. I am able to find lines in matching the regex in notepad++. But, I am not able to replace them with nothing.

How do I do the replacement ?

Comment: Like here, https://regex101.com/r/niH1ba/2?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Thanks. I set "Find what" as ^- Note.* message=(.*)]$ and "Replace with" as $1. Notepad++ says 0 occurrences were replaced. I have selected the regex option in find. So, I don't know why this is not working.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I selected all the text in my temp document and then tried the replace all. It works now. Thanks. Please add this as an answer. I can accept it. thanks

Comment: Find: `.*=|\]`  replace all with `nothing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^- Note.* message=(.*)]$
```

Replace with `$1`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/niH1ba/2/).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `- Note` - `- Note` text
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `message=` -  `message=` text
- `(.*)` - Capturing group 1 (`$1`): any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `]` - a `]` char
- `$` - end of a line.

Notepad++ demo and settings:

[image]